# how to rotate the Rectarealight world axis in threejs

Tags: three.js

I will try this rotateOnWorldAxis function

```
rectAreaLight.rotateOnWorldAxis(new Vector3(1,0,0), rotation.x);
rectAreaLight.rotateOnWorldAxis(new Vector3(0,1,0), rotation.y);
rectAreaLight.rotateOnWorldAxis(new Vector3(0,0,1), rotation.z);
rectAreaLight.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true
rectAreaLight.updateMatrixWorld();`
```

`
not solved.

I need a blender and threejs same rotation purpose I will try to rotate in world space for threejs.

Comment: Instead, try `light.lookAt( x, y, z )` or `light.lookAt( vector3 )`.